# Why is my action creator returning an ReferenceError message when I run the dispatch method in the console?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to test out my action creators by using `store` in the console (in Chrome developer tools), but I keep getting this error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: receiveTodo is not defined`

I've double checked my spelling/for typos, as well as exporting the correct modules, but I still can't seem to find where my mistake is.

**todo_actions.js**

```
export const RECEIVE_TODOS = "RECEIVE_TODOS";
export const RECEIVE_TODO = "RECEIVE_TODO";

export const receiveTodos = todos => ({
  type: RECEIVE_TODOS,
  todos
});

export const receiveTodo = todo => ({
  type: RECEIVE_TODO,
  todo
});
```

**root_reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import todosReducer from './todos_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  todos: todosReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**todos_reducer.js**

```
import { RECEIVE_TODOS, RECEIVE_TODO } from '../actions/todo_actions';

// reducers/todos_reducer.js
const initialState = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    title: "wash car",
    body: "with soap",
    done: false
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    title: "wash dog",
    body: "with shampoo",
    done: true
  }
};

const todosReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  Object.freeze(state);
  let nextState = {};
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_TODOS:
      action.todos.forEach(todo => nextState[todo.id] = todo);
      return nextState;
    case RECEIVE_TODO:
      const newTodo = { [action.todo.id]: action.todo };
      return Object.assign({}, state, newTodo);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default todosReducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/root_reducer';

const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer);
  return store;
}

export default configureStore;
```

**todo_redux.jsx (my entry file)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import configureStore from './store/store';

const store = configureStore();
window.store = store;

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <h1>Todos App</h1>
  );
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const root = document.getElementById('content');
  ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, root);
});
```

Comment: Is receiveTodo also on window? I only see that store is.

Comment: Ah wait! That was it! Thank you. And out of curiosity, I understand why I need to include it on the window for testing purposes, but do I actually need to import these action creators in my entry file later on??